# Rules of firebase rules version 2 according to database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What will be changes in my rules(code) so that I can enable the access to my database for testing purpose. **Specially in line number 3**

My rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {  
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
}
```

[Firebase Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80pe4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `false` to `true` in line 5

Comment: For reference, the exact solution you're suggesting could be found in the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#open_access